# Design Pattern for a very long base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

If I have 8 long methods that will be shared among 4 child classes (not all of them will be using all the methods) some will be use only 2 others 4, etc.

If I create a base class and each of the 4 child classes inherit from the base class then the problem is solved but I am trying to avoid using a very long base class.

I can try to divide the base class in more classes depending on how they are used and then use multiple inheritance, this is another solution.

Is there any other pattern to solve this problem?? What would be the optimal?

Comment: Do you use inheritance as "is a" (for example "apple is a fruit)? If so, then you need to inherit all methods. Otherwise inheritance needn't to be the right solution.

Answer (score 4):

From the way you have posed the question, the first thing you need to seriously consider is whether you need classes at all.

One trap that beginners often fall into is believing that everything has to be in a class.    While it is true that some languages require that, it is an option, but is not necessarily required - and can even be a really bad idea - in C++.

Unless there is an actual "is-a" relationship between the classes (e.g. the base class represents a `Dog` and derived classes represent types of dog) it is probably better not to use inheritance at all.

[There are circumstances where a class hierarchy is appropriate, even if there isn't an "is-a" relationship - but, if your situation was like that, you almost certainly wouldn't need to ask the question you have.]

Instead, I'd simply define eight non-member functions (i.e. that are not members of a class) with appropriate arguments and return type.    The arguments and return value (if any) can be used both to pass information to the function, or to pass information back.

The four classes then call the functions as needed.   From your description, however, it is not even clear that you need those four classes.   Possibly all that is needed is a set of functions that are implemented by calling your "8 long methods".     Those "8 long methods" can be implemented locally to a source file, if you need to prevent other code from calling them.

Generally speaking, aim to make your design as simple as possible.   If that is achievable without having a class hierarchy, or without defining any classes at all, then don't use classes.